# can anyone get p8/table_builder to work with Rails 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Has anyone been able to get p8 / table_builder https://github.com/p8/table_builder gem to work for Rails 3.1?

I don't get any output at all. No error message, no content. Is it just me or does it not work?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling the helper, you need to do so with <%= %>, not like <% %> (the documentation example)

In my case I had to update like this :

```
<% calendar_for ... %>
<% calendar.day ... %>
```

to :

```
<%= calendar_for ... %>
<%= calendar.day ... %>
```

Comment: Good to know. Been wanting to revert back to this.

Comment: When I do this I just get my view file re-rendered and nested where the calendar should be. Any ideas?

Comment: I figured out my issue, had inadvertently installed an older version of table_builder which obviously wasn't Rails 3 compatible.

Answer (score 2):

The solution I found was to choose a different repository:

```
gem 'table_builder', '0.0.3', :git => 'git://github.com/jchunky/table_builder.git'
```

Answer (score 0):

If your view file is just getting re-rendered you should kill your rails server and start a new instance of rails server.